# ggplot2 x-axis scale is not readable or non-existent

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a graduate student who is learning R.  I have been able to learn and solve all other problems by reading questions and answers by other people... up until this point.

My assignment says I have to use ggplot2 to show correlation.  The y-axis scale automatically generates and shows up nicely.  But the x-axis doesn't.

I started with this

```
        size_revenue_correlation<- df %>%ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(size, revenue), y = revenue), color = revenue)+
    geom_point(color = "dark blue")+
    geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$revenue), color = "dark red)+
    labs(title = Correlation Between Store Size and Store Revenue"
    , subtitle = "Larger stores bring greater revenue."
    , x = "size"
    , y = "revenue")+
 theme(
    panel.background = element_blank()
    , axis.text.x = element_blank()
    , panel.grid= element_blank()
    
  )
    
    size_revenue_correlation
```

and got this image where there are just a bunch of black marks on the x-axis instead of a scale.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRpFB.png)

I tried using scale_x_continuous() arguments within my ggplot commands and got the same thing.

I have tried using scales with breaks_pretty and breaks_width with various numbers, but I get no numbers and 2 tick marks.  It always looks the same. Here is my most recent attempt:

```
size_revenue_correlation<- df %>%
ggplot(., aes(x = reorder(size, revenue), y = revenue), color = revenue)+
geom_point(color = "dark blue")+
geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$revenue), color = "dark red")+
labs(title = "Correlation between Store Size and Store Revenue"
, subtitle = "Larger stores bring greater revenue."
, x = "size"
, y = "revenue")+
theme(
panel.background = element_blank()
, axis.text.x = element_blank()
, panel.grid= element_blank()
)
size_revenue_correlation + scale_x_discrete(breaks =
scales::breaks_pretty(1:1200, n = 300))
```

and I get this with nothing on the bottom.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA0CT.png)

I need it to give me some sort of a scale that looks similar to what is on the y-axis.  Can someone offer some help?

Thank you.

Comment: Try without `axis.text.x = element_blank()` as it will remove the x-axis labels.

Comment: ... additionally, what are you trying to achieve by reordering size (which looks like a continuous variable) to a factor via reorder?